# function save ajax error

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

i have made function where i can add a row after confirming. the problem is, after submit button, the tables dont reload and show error function alert.actually data success saved and i have to refresh the page so that the table can reload. here is my ajax jquery code:

```js
function reloadPage()
   {
   window.location.reload()
   }

function save()
{
    $('#btnSave').text('saving...'); //change button text
    $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',true); //set button disable 
    var url;
 
    if(save_method == 'add') {
         url = "<?php echo site_url('activity/save')?>";
    } else {
        url = "<?php echo site_url('activity/update_activity')?>";
    }

 
    // ajax adding data to database
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#form-input').serialize(),
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data)
        {
 
            
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
           reloadPage();
 $('#btnSave').text('save'); //change button text
        $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',false); //set button enable 


    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert('Error adding / update data');
        $('#btnSave').text('save'); //change button text
        $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',false); //set button enable 

    }
});
}
```

```html
<button id="btnSave" onclick="save()" class="btn green">
"fa fa-save"> save</button>
```

my controller:

```html
public function save() {
        $actype      = $this->input->post('actype');
        $activity_name  = $this->input->post('activity_name');
        $project   = $this->input->post('project');
        $portion   = $this->input->post('portion');
        $activity   = $this->input->post('actid');
 

        $data = array(
         'activity_type_id'=>$actype,
  'activity_name' =>$activity_name,
  'project_id' =>$project,
  'portion'  =>$portion,
  'activity_id'  => $activity
            
        );
        $this->activity->insertactivity($data);
 
       redirect("activity/input");
    }
```

after i've clicked button save,alert('Error adding / update data'),but actually after reload page data has saved.
where is code error in my ajax code?

Comment: you have two function save??? in controller and script?

Comment: yes,its wronng or not?

Comment: i think its wrong. why you need two function in one button with same function(save) ?

Comment: save in button redirect to ajax javascript,and in ajax javascript call controller.this is codeigniter.

Comment: try to rename one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Force a reload from the server.

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

When you don't specify `true` the reload may be from the browser cache if available.

Also, in the controller, `redirect("activity/input");` is not the appropriate response to an AJAX request. Try something like this instead.

```
$this->activity->insertactivity($data);
echo json_encode(array('result' => TRUE));
```

Your controller code could also be much more concise. Consider this

```
public function save()
{
    $data = array(
            'activity_type_id' => $this->input->post('actype'),
            'activity_name' => $this->input->post('activity_name'),
            'project_id' => $this->input->post('project'),
            'portion' => $this->input->post('portion'),
            'activity_id' => $this->input->post('actid')
    );

    //Assuming insertactivity returns TRUE if the insert works and FALSE if not
    $results['result'] = $this->activity->insertactivity($data);
    echo json_encode($results);
}
```

You can check the "result" in success function

```
success: function(data)
{
  if(data.result === true)
  {
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    reloadPage();
    $('#btnSave').text('save'); //change button text
    $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',false); //set button enable 
  } else {
    //do something to the DOM to tell about the problem
    //which probably means you should add that to your controller's response.
  }
},
```